# How to transform the result of a query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I want to extract certain information from my db. After making the first query I got a result like this:

```
Name   Description    Status    Count
-------------------------------------------
A       a-desc        S1        200
A       a-desc        S2        50
A       a-desc        S3        102
B       b-desc        S1        10
B       b-desc        S3        12
```

I would like to transform that table to this other:

```
Name   Description    S1     S2     S3
-------------------------------------------
A      a-desc         200    50     102
B      b-desc         10     0      12
```

I want to do this using Postgres. I tried using nested queries but I have not been able at the moment.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: "sql" is a language but implemeted differently by different db vendors, we need to know the brand of database because query syntax does differ. MySQL? Oracle? Postgres? SQL Server? ....

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am using Postgre Sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a "traditional" way of performing a "pivot query" using generic SQL that most rdbms will support:

```
select
  Name   
, Description    
, max(case when status = 'S1' then  count end) as S1   
, max(case when status = 'S2' then  count end) as S2
, max(case when status = 'S3' then  count end) as S3
from (

    your query goes here

    ) d
group by
  Name   
, Description
```

However your database may provide specific features  for a pivot (*if we knew what that is*) but the traditional method is adaptable and useful to know.

Comment: Very useful answer, your pivot query works very well :). I will study this in depth.